# MGTwitterEngine "default" tweet count?

Tags: mgtwitterengine

Here is my issue! I am using MGTwitter Engine and have just about everything working from tweets to screen_names re-tweet count and avatars all placed in the table view. What I do not understand is if I add any type of known "count" it will crash on scrolling after the 19 cell

its always the 19 cell it crashes on...????

This is how I get my count

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{





int count = [tweets count];


// if there's no data yet, return enough rows to fill the screen
   if (count == 0)
    count = kCustomRowCount;


// count = 50; -----this does not work ! it will crash when scrolling!?

return count ; 
return [avatarsURL count];
//return [retweetCount count];
//return [avatars count];


}
```

So if I just return count as seen above "return count;" everything works fine but it gets a random number of tweets every-time ranging from 10 - 20 tweets NEVER more then 20.....what is the sence of having a twitter engine if you caint get more then 20 tweets??? So I go in and add the line you see

"count = 50;" and it crashes on scrolling when it get to the 19th cell! No matter what I make that number it does this.... for example :

```
 count = 21;
```

It will still crash.....???  Confused yet? I am ...... Maybe I am returning the count all wrong and someone can enlighten me on a better way to return your count.... and YES I have the kCustomRowCount defined at the top of my class....

So My first initial reaction was I did something wrong but I looked and looked and looked and can not seem to see what.... then I did some testing and found that it seems to crash on the 19 cell and as we all know iOS integers start at zero. This means there could be a default Tweet Count.

So of course I open MGTwitter Engine and start browsing through with NO luck and I googled it and found there once was a default tweet count of 20 tweets in MGTwitterEngine.h but NOT in my version !!! So I just added the #define and that doesnt work! So if ANYONE has ANY suggestion on how to fix this or if there is or isnt a default tweet count so I can cancel that out of the equation !

Thank you I hope to find a solution soon!

Answer (score 0):

in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m uncomment

```
if (params) {
      fullPath = [self _queryStringWithBase:fullPath parameters:params   
        prefixed:YES];
    }
```

as shown below! your welcome.....

```
 #define SET_AUTHORIZATION_IN_HEADER 1

 - (NSString *)_sendRequestWithMethod:(NSString *)method 
                            path:(NSString *)path 
                 queryParameters:(NSDictionary *)params 
                            body:(NSString *)body 
                     requestType:(MGTwitterRequestType)requestType 
                    responseType:(MGTwitterResponseType)responseType
{
NSString *fullPath = path;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// modificaiton from the base clase
// the base class appends parameters here
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  if (params) {
//       fullPath = [self _queryStringWithBase:fullPath parameters:params   
    //    prefixed:YES];
    }
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@/%@", 
                       (_secureConnection) ? @"https" : @"http",
                       _APIDomain, fullPath];
  NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
  if (!finalURL) {
    return nil;
  }
```